# I am an LDAP user. Why can't I change my shell despite being listed in /etc/shells?

Tags: ldap, shell

I can't change my shell. The following shell output shows what I have tried. How can I change my shell to `/usr/bin/fish`?

```
[michael@vps ~]$ chsh.ldap -s /usr/bin/fish michael
/usr/bin/chsh.ldap: /usr/bin/fish is an invalid shell
[michael@vps ~]$ cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/fish
```

Comment: Are you sure that chsh.ldap on your system checks /etc/shells and not some other (presumably domain-wide) configuration file?